# How to use Box2D physics engine into an openCV project?

Tags: c++, opencv, box2d

I am studying the openCV and Box2D and I am going to DIY a game.This is how it works:
First we put in a picture with black thick lines, then do the edge detection to produce the edge.

Then comes the trouble, I want to use these edges as the "staticBody" in the Box2D engine but I just can't find a way to "transform" the edges into the Body.Actually the edges are going to be used as walls in the game, and there will be a small virtual point represents  something like a motion ball. All you have to do is control the point and move it to the destination.The openCV is used to processing the image so that you can draw your map on the paper and start your game.

I'm a newbie on Box2D by the way, so how can I do?

Comment: Why do the edges need to be transformed?